# Laravel Migration Failed After The First File/Run(except file for creating users and password_reset table)

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I tried making database using Laravel Migration, it works only in first file and run... after that, I don't know what it caused to fail. I made  date, head, and many more for the database, date successfully implemented but head fail even after I remove date migration file and using limiter on interger didn't give any effect.
Error Screenshot

[image]

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mono
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Localhost

[image]

**create_head_table.php**

```
   <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    
    class CreateHeadTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('head', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('head', 50);
                $table->interger('tgl', 50);
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('head');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove length from integer. $table->interger('tgl'); or choose another type of integer. you can not specify integer length.

Comment: Well, it's a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your "create_head_table.php" migration file. As of your image the error occurs on line 19 and so why?
In the `up` function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('head', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('head', 50);
        $table->interger('tgl', 50);//$table->integer('tgl'); or $table->string('tgl', 50);
    });
}
```

Is the last field of table `integer` or `string`? If it is `string` so plz correct it but if it is `integer` your syntax is wrong. The second parameter in integer is `autoincrement` not length!!

Refer [Here](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer) for more information.

Comment: Oh... yes, it is syntax typo. thank you and sorry for this error of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have an spelling mistake in here `$table->interger('tgl', 50);`. It will be `integer` not `interger`.